Waive MFA for exempt users not overriding as advertised
The Waive MFA permission states:
Disable MFA challenges on direct UI logins for users or orgs that aren’t required by Salesforce to use multi-factor authentication, per the Salesforce Trust and Compliance Documentation. This permission overrides the Multi-Factor Authentication for User Interface Logins user permission and the Require multi-factor authentication (MFA) for all direct UI logins to your Salesforce org setting.

I assign my user two permissions:

Waive Multi-Factor Authentication for Exempt Users
Multi-Factor Authentication for User Interface Logins

I then go to the SSO SAML and enforce MFA by enabling the following setting :

Use Salesforce MFA for this SSO Provider

I would expect the MFA to not get enforced as the SSO setting above requires  (Waive Multi-Factor Authentication for Exempt Users) but that should have gotten overriden by the
(Multi-Factor Authentication for User Interface Logins). However MFA is getting enforced.
I know I would normally not assign the two permissions like that to my user however with auto enablement of MFA by Salesforce in near future, it makes me nervous that the (Waive Multi-Factor Authentication for Exempt Users) may not work for users that we have designated as exempt (integration users etc).
What am I missing?

Those first two permissions do not apply to SSO, they're "native" login (and a few other paths) only.

@identigral Thanks for that. But SSO MFA enforcement, can only happen with the presence of 'Multi-Factor Authentication for User Interface Logins' which is stated next to the option under SSO settings. That permission is not getting overriden by the waive MFA. That is all I am saying.

Regarding MFA auto-enablement in the near future, SF has been threatening to do so for  years and it still hasn't happened.  With SSO as the access pathway, technically there's no way for the service provider (SF) to know if MFA has been performed by the identity provider. See this related question.

Makes sense. Thank you for the link.
